# how set Image height and width from server ?

Tags: android

I can fetch the all the images from server database using json through url. i display all images in listview how can give images height and width

This is main.java

```
    JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);// calls main.xml
    adapter=new ImageAdapter(this, json);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  Imageadapter.java
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Bitmap bmp;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    String qrimage;
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
            itemname = image.getString("itemname");
            map.put("itemname", image.getString("itemname"));
            System.out.println(itemname);

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    return mImages[position];

}
  }
 My xml view
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />


 </LinearLayout>
```

The above code is display the images from server database to android to the list view.
How can i set height and width of those images ?

Comment: Using an ImageView, just set the Width and Height properties? Unless you are talking about Scaling a Bitmap, in which case you can use the BitmapFactor class for this

Comment: **IS it really a good idea to set height/width from server?**

Answer (score 0):

After converting bytes into bitmap. Please ask bitmap to tell his height , width

```
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                        qrimageBytes.length);

    // Ask Height and width from bitmap.
    Log.e("Image Height" , " Height = "+bmp.getHeight() + " , Width = "+ bmp.getWidth() );

        mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);

        // Use LayououtParams to se your imageView hegiht , width

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(new LayoutParams( bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()));
        mImages[i].setLayoutParams(params);

        // And don't forget to set your imageView scale type. 
        img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        // Then set your bitmap
        mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: it gets height and width of the image i want set height and width manually. according to the image and width it displays image.please tell me how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Which layout you are using to display ListView Rows? You need to use custom ListView to display images and text. Give me some part of your code. I'll arrange that for you.

Comment: ya i want display custom listview images and text please replay

Comment: You'll have to create another XML Layout to display ListView Row. You are displaying images. So you should try Lazy Loading for images.

Comment: Try these: (1) https://github.com/thest1/LazyList   (2) http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

Well the most easy way to do this is to let the server return the `width` and `height` in its json as a property.

Using Bitmaps is problematic because you will get `OutOfMemory` Errors if they are too  big.